# Screencast live from Ubuntu to TV

Tags: linux, video, screen-sharing

I am looking for some software to cast the content of the screen to my TV in the other room wireless. I know there's Chromecast but it's additional device which I don't want - especially given the fact that YouTube is able to run videos without it. So what soft should I use for that?

As for technicalities. I run a up-to-date Lubuntu on my laptop (Ubuntu with LXDE as a window manager) and the TV is Samsung ue48ju6050. I'm not exactly sure what OS it runs on but it has Play Store so I bet some variation of Android or Chrome OS... Oh, I want mostly cast a videos (Netflix and Amazon Prime don't have all I like - especially cartoons are better in Polish :) )

Comment: What receiver(s) does your TV have?  Wi-Fi? Bluetooth? That is more important than its OS.  That is the facility that a Chromecast gives you.

Comment: I use Wifi, don't know what's else on the board - don't even have a tv signal connected.